# How to scroll div with page without position: fixed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I found this script:

```
$(function(){
var btn = $('.social');
var btnPosTop = btn.offset().top;
var win = $(window);
win.scroll(function(e){
var scrollTop = win.scrollTop();
if(scrollTop >= btnPosTop){
btn.css({position:'fixed',left:'82%'});
}else if(btn.css('position') === 'fixed'){
btn.css({position:'',left:''});
}
});
});
```

Which works great. I changed the original field to '.social' so that it would work with my code.

I am not looking for a crap fix of "left: 82%" though.
I want to avoid the position: fixed; and simply scroll the div where it sits.

My tree is #container .contain .single-content .social

The position: fixed is my main problem, but if you know, then stopping .social once it reaches the very bottom of .single-content would be a major plus!!

Hopefully I have provided enough information.

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
<div class='contain'>
<div class='single-content'>
<div class='first'>
<div class='social'>

content here.. no p tags.. just facebook, twitter buttons etc.

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div><!-- container -->
```

EDIT:
website in question: [thelackof.com](http://www.thelackof.com/does-choice-exist-or-is-everything-predestined/)

You can see how the social icons are offset a bit because of my left:82%
If I remove the left:, then the new position: fixed will jump my div out of the containing div and all the way to the left of the next containing div.

I would like it to stay where it is and scroll down once reached.

Comment: Post the actual HTML please (the important parts).

Comment: Update the question, don't post it in the comments section.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Please actually read the preceding link and make sure that the code you post **in your question** is **minimal** (only bare minimum of code necessary to reproduce), **complete** (all of the code necessary to reproduce) and **verifiable** (we can reproduce the issue using only the code in your question). Without a proper MCVE **in your question**, this question is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: No no no. I was asked to provide my HTML through "edit", which I did. I then continued to update my question when no one had the "big picture". Thus, my question exists as is. My code IS minimal as it contains what is REQUIRED. My question is very complete and yes, it is verifiable. Thanks anyway nazi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT no. 2:** First of all:

So it will get a value that won't disturb with the main-contents:

```
#container .contain .single-content .first .social {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    width: 15%;
    right: 0;
}
```

Then this:

```
$(function(){
var btn = $('.social');

var btnPosTop = btn.offset().top;
var win = $(window);
win.scroll(function(e){
var scrollTop = win.scrollTop();
if(scrollTop >= btnPosTop){
btn.css({position:'fixed'});
}else if(btn.css('position') === 'fixed'){
btn.css({position:''});}
if (btnPosTop >= $('.single-content').offset().top-92){
    btn.css({position:''});
}
});
});
```

I might be getting your question wrong but I think this is what you asked for. I removed the left property.

Hope it helps :)

**EDIT:** I've added:

```
if (btnPosTop >= $('.single-content').offset().top){
    btn.css({position:''});
}
```

So it will scroll until the btnPosTop is greater than the offset().top of .single-content

Please let me know if it works

Comment: Sorry, I only added the left: as a temporary fix. Need .social, which is to scroll when reached, to stay exactly where it is when reached (stay on the right of the div). Instead, it jumps to the far left of the containing div with position: fixed. I need that to not happen.

Comment: You don't want `.social` to get the `position:fixed`?

Comment: Nope, that is how the script made it when I first found it online. The "fixed" sends my `.social` out of sync with my page and jumps it to the far left of the containing div (.first). So I need the fixed changed so that social will stay where it is (position: relative;), but .social will not scroll with my page with a relative position.

Comment: The problem is that fixed items have "no height and width" thats why it "ignores" all the content on the left. Working on an answer!

Comment: Thank you! Interesting to know that, I would have never figured what height or width were actually behind "fixed". Thank you for helping me with this.

Comment: Thank you thank you! Oddly the new script you provided after "Then this:" caused the entire function to no longer work, but I kept what originally you had provided me with and it is working great. A few css issues but I have it from there. Thank you for the help